# alternatives for "leveraging"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Some people frown upon the use of "leveraging" in formal writing. What would be a good alternative to the expression:

> We will be able to investigate X **leveraging** from the knowledge of
>   Y.

None of the entries in thesaurus seem to neatly apply to the case. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

*Applying*, *using* (and I suppose *utilising*, but frankly I'd much prefer *leveraging* to that), "making use of"

Your *from* is incorrect above, by the way. It should be "We will be able to investigate X, leveraging the knowledge of Y", and hence "We will be able to investigate X, applying the knowledge of Y" and so on.

Comment: Downvoter care to comment?

Comment: In line with _applying_ and _using_: _exerting_.

Comment: @garageàtrois not really, there is some overlap, but not a lot. One couldn't use *exerting* in the sentence in the question and have the same meaning.

Answer (score 2):

The term I would use is "building upon."

We were able to investigate X, **building upon** our knowledge of Y.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative could be:

> "We will be able to investigate X, ***benefitting from*** the knowledge
>   of Y"

Comment: Downvoter - would you please leave some feedback?

Comment: Too late, she cried ...

Answer (score 1):

First off, the "verb" leverage is on my list of unaccepted words. I will gladly use "getting leverage" or "taking advantage" but prefer using a verb like "benefit" or even "exploit." Actually, I believe that most people would like to use the verb "exploit" but believe it sounds wrong.

Comment: Welcome to the English Language and Usage Stack Exchange. Answers are encouraged to be supported by authoritative sources, and appear authoritative rather than personal opinion.

Answer (score 0):

*Leveraging* was coined as the concept of using something to maximum advantage, bring into effective use, or use in a strategic way, especially something that has not been done or was not the norm. Today, the term serves a very useful purpose when used carefully and effectively. There are no words or short phrases that convey the exact sense. Nothing wrong with leveraging a powerful term, I feel.

That said, "*leveraging from the knowledge of Y*" is incorrect use and defeats the purpose and fails to use the power of the term. Say, instead,

> We will be able to investigate X leveraging <strike>from</strike> the knowledge of Y.

or better still,

> We can leverage our knowledge of Y to investigate X.